# To check the file contents line by line

Tags: powershell

I need to check the contents line by line by selecting the string of the line.
I have declared each line matching string to a variable.Is it possible to use switch cases for looking into the variables

I have used if condition to check the each line with the help of variables .
I wanted to know whether we could use switch cases?

Consider file.txt having following contents :

```
$q = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hello' -SimpleMatch

$w = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'new' -SimpleMatch

$e = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'World' -SimpleMatch

$r = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'Hi' -SimpleMatch

$t = Get-Content -Path .\file.txt |Select-String 'greet' -SimpleMatch
```

So can we check the variables using the switch options. Is it possible to output the variables which are not present. How can we achieve the same if the file contents are large?

Can we use switch options and output the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know which of the 5 words are not in any of the lines in the file, you can do this

```
$Pattern = 'Hello|new|World|Hi|greet'
$Test = (Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches).foreach{$_.matches.Value}
$($pattern -split '\|').where{$Test -notcontains $_}
```

But is that your goal?

Comment: The solution which you gave matches with my concern. The text file is large one and I have numerous strings/ words to check. Can we use the same  for that?

Comment: Thanks @Axel Anderson , The solution gives desired output

Comment: Anderson,The solution doesn't work for power shell 2.0 version. Is there any option to make the above code snippet work in power shell 2.0 version

Comment: Try this:

$Test =(Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches) | foreach {$_.matches.Value}

$($pattern -split '\|') | where {$Test -notcontains $_}

Comment: still not able to get the result in powershell 2.0

Comment: when the new solution is tried i get the error as below:                                                  Foreach object : Cannot convert 'System.object[]' to type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by a paramter 'Process'.Specified method is not supported in powershell 2.0

Comment: $Pattern = 'Hello|new|World|Hi|greet'
    $Test =(Get-Content -Path .\file.txt | Select-String -Pattern $Pattern -AllMatches) | foreach {$_.matches.Value}
    $($pattern -split '\|') | where {$Test -notcontains $_} 
Works in Windows Powershell 3.0 +. I do not have access to a system with 2.0 on it.

Comment: Im trying to figure out in powershell 2.0 what does $($pattern -split '\|') in your solution does?

Comment: That makes a string array of the Pattern variable